# A 10 characters password, each character being a lowercase letter or a digit and must contain at least one digit and at most three digits.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have forgotten a lot of the counting portion of my discrete structures course and need some explanations how to count, maybe some general strategies on counting.

Some example questions I need explaining are

2. A password consists of 10 characters, each character being a lowercase letter or a digit. A
   password must contain at least one digit and at most three digits. How many passwords are
   there?

a) $\binom{10}{1}26^9+\binom{10}{2}26^8+\binom{10}{3}26^7$

b) $10\times26^9+10^2\times26^8+10^3\times26^7$

c) $\binom{10}{1}\times10\times26^9+\binom{10}{2}\times10^2\times26^8+\binom{10}{3}\times10^3\times26^7$

d) None of the above

If anyone can help explain these questions to me that would be appreciated!

Edit. I feel like it is C. but not sure

Answer (score 1):

you are correct that it is (c). What is going on is that we are choosing WHERE to put our digits. if we only have 1 digit, we have $\binom{10}{1}$ places to put it: then we have 10 choices for our digit and $26^9$ choices for our other letters. if we have two digits, we have $\binom{10}{2}$ places to put them, $10^2$ choices for what they are, etc.

If you extend this to there being anywhere from 0 to 10 digits, this becomes the binomial expansion $26^{10} + \binom{10}{1}10^1 26^9 + \binom{10}{2}10^2 26^8 + \dots + \binom{10}{9}10^9 26^1 + 10^{10}$. Why does this make sense? because this is $(26+10)^{10}$, which is what you get if any input can be a letter or number, aka you have 36 choices in each slot.